# Question on understanding monerod command Flush_txpool and the bug that resulted

Tags: monerod, full-node, txpool, monerod-commands

Now that I've been running a node consistently now, I've been trying to understand the commands given listed in 'help'. Recently, I noticed a tx id that has sat in the mempool for over a day.

First, is that a circumstance when flush_txpool [tx id] should be used? Otherwise, what is its purpose?

Next, in attempting to paste the tx id into the command, it instead started entering commands like '260302.305830' or something similar to peer data. This was not even on my computer's clipboard.

What would cause this?

It should be noted that I was not able to repeat the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flush_txpool` command can be used to flush an individual transaction, list of transactions (by RPC command) or the entire transaction pool.

A use-case like you describe (flushing a transaction that has been sitting for a long time without confirmation) would be a normal use for the tool. Another purpose could involve network load or dynamic block-size testing, where excess transactions are flushed at the end of the test.

> Next, in attempting to paste the tx id into the command, it instead started entering commands like '260302.305830' or something similar to peer data. This was not even on my computer's clipboard.

What operating system were you using and exactly how were you attempting to paste the tx id into monerod?

> It should be noted that I was not able to repeat the issue.

This probably is because what you described was a copy/paste error.

Comment: Windows 10 64bit. Using most recent version of monerod. Using right-click which autopastes for some reason